# ¿Como puedo usar la misma Deploy key en un repositorio y en un submodulo?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken-git-gui

Estoy realizando un repositorio privado en **GitHub** y dentro de este algunos submódulos, sin embargo, al intentar realizar cambios dentro del submódulo me aparece el siguiente mensaje.

```
Push Failed
ERROR: Permision to empresa/repositorio.git denied to deploy key
```

Cabe mencionar que estoy usando **Git Kraken** para administrar los repositorios y ya tengo agregada a repositorio "padre" por así decirlo, una deploy key que generé también con Git Kraken

Comment: ¿Tienes todos los permisos habilitados?

Comment: ya lo corregí, tenía que agregar la key a mi perfil & no al proyecto, para poder usarlo en todos los repositorios que incluyan mi usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La deploy key de git kraken (o el servicio ssh de tu preferencia) se agrega directamente al usuario, para que en todos los repositorios en los que estás como colaborador puedas usar la misma key.

Esto se hace desde los ajustes del usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]